# Search by date in WordPress

Tags: php, functions

The default Wordpress search works only for titles. I want for it to search by date. My default date format: 2012/02/24

I have managed to add a code to functions.php for 'custom field' search:

```
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {    
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );


function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $pagenow, $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );


function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_search() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

Is there any code that will let the Wordpress search by date (default Wordpress)?

Basically I want to type 2012/02/24 in the search box and all the post made that date would be displayed in the search results.

I'm not good with coding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know how you would do this specifically, **but**, if you use URL parameters you can go to individual date archives or filter archives by date. A form that has input fields with the same names as the `WP_Query` date parameters would let you search using a dropdown or a textbox for each part, e.g. `<input type="number" name="year" value="2020" />`

Comment: What I mean, is that for some reason wordpress doesn't allow date searches.
For example, if you go to http://www.stockiii.com/ and type 2021/02/24 in the search box, It would say that nothing is found. But you will see that the post does contains the date 2021/02/24.

Comment: That's because WP doesn't support text based date searches out of the box, but as I mentioned, it isn't the only way to enable filtering by date in a form, which is why I left a comment, not a solution/answer

Comment: If only I knew how to do that. Basically I want to have a few links: Today, Yesterday, 7 days, 1 month, 3 month, 1 year, all time. When you click, it will display posts made by that period. The only logical way I figured I could do that is by using the search /?s=2012/02/24
I'm not a coder, but I guess I will keep on searching.

Comment: My first comment told you how to do it, re-read it, it includes an example of what the input tag would be, there is no PHP or javascript involved, just HTML forms and inputs